# Change numbering within a clause

Tags: numbering, scrjura

I write a contract amendment using `scrjura`.

```
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[juratotoc]{scrjura}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\parformat}{%
    \global\hangindent 2em
    \makebox[2em][l]{(\thepar)\hfill}\hspace{-0,3cm}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{contract}
        \Clause{title={Title}, number=2}

        \blindtext

    \end{contract}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: result]

By default, the first paragraph within a clause is numbered (1). How can I change the code so that I can choose which number the sentence begins with?
Also, if there is only one paragraph within a clause, the number disappears. How do I deal with this?

Desired is:

[image: desired]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two solutions:

Before a paragraph, `\thisparnumber` can be used to set the paragraph number.

```
\begin{contract}
    \Clause{title={Title}, number=2}
        
    \thisparnumber{2}% <----- sets paragraph number
    \blindtext

\end{contract}
```

---

But if you want to set a group of paragraphs starting from e.g. 2, it is not recommended to use `\thisparnumber`, because the option leaves the counter `par` untouched. If you do not want to number all paragraphs manually, you can set the starting point for an automatic count with `\setcounter{par}{1}`.

```
\begin{contract}
    \Clause{title={Title}, number=2}
         
    \setcounter{par}{1}% <----- sets paragraph counter
    \blindtext

\end{contract}
```